# Django class-based views vs function views performance

Tags: django, python-3.x, performance

Is there performance difference between class-based and function views?
Is **instance created** every time there's request to class based view, or **not**?
What about memory?

Should I use function views or class views to achieve best performance under high load?

Comment: Yes an instance is created each time but this has absolutely no performance implications, as it is just one of many many classes that are instantiated. The difference is not at all one of performance.

Comment: Use Class based vew, it's better for maintainability.